# How to access a nested object with string paths?

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I'm trying to access properties of a JavaScript object by passing a path (string or otherwise):

```
// In a loop
tableData[i].profile.firstname
```

where `'profile.firstname'` is the path.

Is there a way to access a nested property based on a path in this way?

```
let firstnamePath = 'profile.firstname'
let firstname     = tableData[i][firstnamePath]
```

Comment: Also [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491463/accessing-nested-javascript-objects-with-string-key).

Comment: @Amadan yes there are several good duplicates but they're a pain to find :)

Comment: They are quite similar, but IMO not duplicates, the answer below is quite different and is what I was looking for, because I can use complex paths with such a functional approach

Comment: With Lodash: `_.get(tableData[i], 'profile.firstname')`

Comment: Without lodash: `'profile.firstname'.split('.').reduce((_, x) => _[x], tableData)` =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not with the syntax you've proposed. This is easiest done when your path is an array of strings:

```js
const tableData = (
  { profile: { firstname: 'jim', lastname: 'johnson' }
  }
)
                                                                    
const path = [ 'profile', 'firstname' ]

const valueAtPath = path.reduce((_, x) => _[x], tableData)

console.info(valueAtPath)
```

Comment: I'll try this right now

Comment: This solution works nicely !